# Google sign in button and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

I'm in the process of trying to embed a google sign in button into our project. I have something set up that works for the most part but there's one remaining issue where the button isn't displayed on first render but will show up after the page with that component is refreshed:
https://d.pr/i/AT36oQ

I suspect that something needs to be added to a componentDidUpdate() method in that component but I haven't yet been able to figure out what that is.

Here's a copy of the top level html:
[image]

Here's the render method of the component with the g-signin2 element:
[image]